# Dynamic Form Name for redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Is there any way to have a dynamic form name for [redux-form](https://redux-form.com/)?

```
reduxForm({
  form: `${dynamicFormNameHere}`,
})(Component)
```

> Note: Container = Smart Component, Component = Dumb Component

Currently I have a container (e.g. `FilterContainer`) that wrap a component with fields, and I use that container in several components. Examples:

```
// UserComponent.jsx
...
render() {
  ...
  <FilterContainer dynamicName="UserFilterForm" { ... } />
}

// ProductComponent.jsx
...
render() {
  ...
  <FilterContainer dynamicName="ProductFilterForm" { ... } />
}
```

and inside `FilterContainer`

```
mapStateToProps() { ... }
mapDispatchToProps() { ... }

let FilterContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(reduxForm({
  form: `${dynamicName from props}`
}}(FilterComponent))
```

That `dynamicName from props` is what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this you will need to introduce a new component that wraps the `reduxForm` Higher-Order Component (HOC).  Something like:

```
class DynamicFilterComponent extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.Filter = reduxForm({
      form: this.props.dynamicName
    })(FilterComponent)
  }

  render() {
    const Filter = this.Filter
    return <Filter {...this.props} />
  }
}
```

Then wrap this in `connect`:

```
mapStateToProps() { ... }
mapDispatchToProps() { ... }

let FilterContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(DynamicFilterComponent)
```

**Note:** When dealing with HOCs you must be careful when creating them dynamically.  I created the `reduxForm` HOC in `componentWillMount` so that it is the same instance used for each render call.  [This is important for React's diffing algorithm](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method).